# How to highlight a row if two cells in the row not contain the same text

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I need to set up conditional formatting in Google Sheets to highlight an entire row if the text in column D is not found in column C in each row.

Custom formulas tried:

```
=COUNTIF($C:$C,$D2)
```

tested to get the rows to highlight if the cells in column C are the same as column D.  This worked (but I need it to highlight the opposite rows - if they are not equal) if there is only one entry in column D.

[image]

Comment: try `=ISERROR(SEARCH($D2,$C2))`

Comment: Yes!  That worked!  Except it's now highlighting the rows where column C and column D are NULL (blank rows).  How would I exclude these from being highlighted?

Comment: `=AND($D2<>"",ISERROR(SEARCH($D2,$C2)))`

Comment: Yes!!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
=AND($C2<>"", NOT(COUNTIF($C2,$D2)))
```

[image: 0]